# Read data from serial port in FreeRTOS

Tags: c, freertos, nucleo

We have a issue during reading data from serial port. The C function which is used to read data have a argument for the data size in bytes. In order to read data  we need to know in advance the size of the incoming data. We use RFID reader via serial port connection. Data is send to Nucleo board in different size each time.
The other problem that we face is the Nucleo interruption during reading data. When we receive the data in height speed we need to initiate it again. This leads to data loss in height data transfer speeds.
One possible solution will be to use DMA(direct memory access) but we are not familiar wit this approach.
Can you propose some solution?

Answer (score 0):

I find your question confusing as you don't clearly state what the issue you are having is and you make assumptions that others will know how the functions you are calling are implemented.  In any case is sounds unrelated to FreeRTOS.